# Symfony2 + Doctrine manage big size of Data generate error: Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5131594 bytes)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata

I'm using Symfony2 for my project and in my model, some of the entities are so many (more than 150 000 instances) I'm using the ORM Doctrine2 to persist them in the Database Management System MySQL the problem is that after fixturing one table with only 26 000 rows I can't load one of the page of my project again. Symfony2 throw the following error each time allthough I edited the `php.ini` file by increasing the memory size to from 128 to 512 M and clear the cache.

> error generated by Symfony (2.7) :OutOfMemoryException in Profile.php
>   line 153:
>
> Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 5131594 bytes)

Notice that I'm using sonata-adminBundle also to manage my entities.

Comment: Maybe you should try to optimise the way you display/load your entities then, by not charging them all at once for example.

Comment: I realized that in production mod every thing worke fine but the error still occur in dev mod

Answer (score 4):

There are at least four ways to decrease memory usage:

1) enforce garbage collector to do its job `gc_collect_cycles();`

2) clear entity manager to detach objects if you don't need them anymore

```
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

3) disable SQL logger, for instance

```
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

[Here](http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2013/01/18/how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-symfony-2-commands/) you can read a bit more.

4) use [doctrine pagination](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) where you have to handle a lot of entities

Comment: +1, although I recommend **never** doing solution nr. 1 . That would be treating the symptom instead of the disease.

Comment: @RaduMurzea thanks for comment :) Well, it's up to you which way(s) to use ;)

Comment: First of all thank you for your help Sergekv but notice that symfony2 generate the error when I dont load the entities and also when Iiintentionaly load all the enties there is not any error at all and the page that use to generate error doesn't when using prod mode. Also I edited php.ini and increase the memero size and the maxi execution time...

Comment: 3) did the job for me